# Is Visual Studio 2015 for Mac exists?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-mac

Is Visual Studio 2015 for Mac exists ?
If yes, does it support TFS binding with MAC ?

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2017 community for MAC edition which has only Git and SVN repository options available.

But for development, I may not have VS2017 for MAC, I need to check if VS2015 is available for MAC or not ?

And, Will VS2017 for MAC Xamarin.iOS project work with VS2015 for MAC ?

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: it should work with TFS. did you try connecting using team services? https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/ their site says, you will be able to use team services . But, VS 2015 is not available for mac.

Comment: Thanks for a reply Tazbir.
VSTS provided repositories are on cloud.
Suppose i need configure local TFS server like i do for SVN then how could i connect that with Visual Studio for Mac ?
And before Visual Studio 2017 for mac, which version was running on mac, please could you tell me ?

Thanks !

Comment: i think the procedure to connect to local and cloud is same. they both use the same protocol. you can follow this steps to setup that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/user-guide/connect-team-projects . answer to your second question would be, there were no VS support for mac before VS 2017 . VS code was built for multi platform support from the start and VS 2017 is the first full featured VS version to run on mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Visual Studio 2015 for Mac is not exists. Before VS2017 for mac, there is a preview version, details please refer: [Announcing the new Visual Studio for Mac](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/11/16/visual-studio-for-mac/)

If you could not work with VS2017 for MAC and want to connect to TFS/VSTS. You could try to use **[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)** , which is more of a quick; light weight code editor.

With the help of [Visual Studio Team Services extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.team) on Visual Studio Code, it allows you to connect to Team Services and Team Foundation Server and provides support for both Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC), GIT.

Comment: Thanks Patrick for a reply.
Actually I need to develop a Xamarin.iOS application. I'm not sure if Visual Studio Code does have support for that or not. I googled it but there is no official link which says it supports Xamarin projects.

I've opened my account on VSTS which allows me to select source control either GitHub or TFVC.. but it would store my code on there cloud.

I need to configure my internal TFS server with Visual Studio.

Comment: @NikhilDekhane If you are worrying about the extension of VS Code, it's also support with on- premise TFS. If you want to configure you internal TFS, just install the on-premise TFS such as TFS2017 update2 at your side. As for if Xamarin.IOS application is support with Visual Studio Code or not. Yes there is not any official statement, but according to this post it work limited on a Mac, https://mikebluestein.com/2015/04/29/visual-studio-code-with-xamarin-on-a-mac/

Comment: @Patric-MSFT, Yes, i saw that link.. actually he is saying on the first look he was able to open the code in the editor but he did not mentioned about the designer view and other things.. so I may need to try it out.

Regarding on-premise TFS, Visual Studio 2017 for Mac only allows me to connect with 'Git' and 'Subversion' repositories. There is no option to connect with on-premise TFS.

Comment: @NikhilDekhane Yes you are right. This is not yet available, not include TFS in VS for MAC by now. You can see the uservoice here https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/563332-visual-studio-for-mac/suggestions/17136163-tfs-version-control  
It's the  top voted item  and this will be implemented sooner since it is under review as of now.

Comment: Thanks ! from that link it is clear that they don't have TFS support with their Mac version